# SQL Server command to return query result as json not working with python

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server

I want to convert the SQL query result as json using SQL statement with Python. This is the SQL command I am trying

```
select * 
from mydb 
for json auto
```

I also tried `for json path`.

And I also tried with `without_array_wrapper` but its returning only one row from the list.

If I run the query without `for json auto|path`, it's returning 8 rows, but when I run it with `for json auto|path`, I only get 4 rows (instead of 8), and its converting the 8 rows into 4 and returns an array of 4.

This is my Python code

```
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Can somebody please help me figure out and fix this issue?

Comment: If you put `FOR JSON AUTO` at the end of a statement you will get 1 row, that's correct. Why would you expect more? Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @larnu thank you for your reply.. the data is huge it has 41 columns. so i could not paste it here. when i run query without for json path its returning 8 row and its working fine .. but when i run query with json path  its converting 8 rows into 4 json objects.

Comment: @MiladDastanZand thank you .... actually there is no error the problem is its converting 8 rows into 4 json object instead of 8.

Comment: @tstudent , We just need a [mre], emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Try `SELECT CAST((select * from mydb for json auto) AS nvarchar(max))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FOR JSON PATH results in SSMS truncated to 2033 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973536/for-json-path-results-in-ssms-truncated-to-2033-characters) It's a known issue with `FOR JSON`

Comment: @Larnu Please mark this as duplicate

Comment: @Charlieface I can't hammer a question that is already closed. Nor can a hammer a question I have already made a VTC on.

Comment: @Larnu Oh I thought a gold badge could change the VTC reason

Comment: Nope, @Charlieface , we can only unilaterally close and reopen as dupes, and (just like everyone else) we only get 1 VTC on a question. If i VTC as unclear, I can't then VTC as a dupe later on if we get clarrification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this solution .

```
Select cast ((select * from mydb for json auto) as nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: Nothing to do with pyodbc, it's documented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973536/for-json-path-results-in-ssms-truncated-to-2033-characters/54973676