# Azure Function not able to pull more than 100+ columns from Azure SQL Table

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have created an Azure function app that queries Azure SQL table and returns the data back as a JSON . The azure function runs successfully, however it is not able to pull more than 100 columns from the SQL Table. The JSON is truncated after 100 columns.

Is this an issue by design or do you think I may be doing something wrong ?

Comment: Is it, perhaps, actually being [truncated after 2033 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973536/for-json-path-results-in-ssms-truncated-to-2033-characters)?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not about the 100 columns, but for the JSON data type the data truncates itself after 2033 characters. So this is the default behavior and limitation for JSON.

One possible workaround is to iterate through the results concatenating the rows which have been returned.